# remove last slides on slick depending on breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am really not into JS, so I have just googled a lot, but didnt find a solution, so I need to ask for your help.

I have the slick slider and 5 breakpoints. Because of crazy the positioning I have to include empty slides at the end. This works for desktop where I show 5 Slides, so I need 4 empty slides at the end. But on the first breakpoint on 1500 I change to 4 slides to show. No I need to delete the last (empty) slide.

On 1200 I need to delete another one.
On 900 another one and so on.

So, what I am looking for:

Breakpoint 1500 or less - delete the last slide,
Breakpoint 1200 or less - delete the last 2 slides, 
Breakpoint 900 or less - delete the last 3 slides, 
Breakpoint 600 or less - delete the last 4 slides

It would be awesome, if somebody could help me.
Thanks a lot!

What I have at the moment is:

$(document).ready(function(){

```
var docWidth = $( document ).width();
var winWidth = $(window).width();


if(docWidth>500 && docWidth<700 )
{
  $('.slider').slick('slickRemove',4);
}
```

});

Now slide 4 is removed between 500 and 700. (Don't mind the breakpoints 500/700, it was just a test)

But the number of slides changes daily. So I need to count down from the last item. I tried

$('.slider').slick('slickRemove',slideIndex - 1);

to pick the last ones each time, but it do not work.

See my fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/ug87nb8d/

Comment: Your question is too broad and therefore off topic for SO.  But you would probably need to add a window resize event and depending on your width, you would need to destroy the of instance of your slick carousel and re-initialise it with the required amount of slides

Comment: thanks @Pete added some information to my question and a fiddle. hope it is more clear now :S